# Create dynamic xml parametrized block with groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a comma-separated list/array as input to the groovy script. based on the number of elements in the array, I need to create parameterized XML block like below.

eg if the input is CAT,DOG

I need to create an XML block like below

```
<v2:values>
  <v2:item>CAT</v2:item>
  <v2:item>DOG</v2:item>
</v2:values>
```

if the input is CAT,DOG,ROSE

I need output as

```
<v2:values>
  <v2:item>CAT</v2:item>
  <v2:item>DOG</v2:item>
  <v2:item>ROSE</v2:item>
</v2:values>
```

if Input is empty I need output block as empty

I wrote a groovy script like this

```
if(input.contains(","))
{   
    String[] param_array = input1[0].split(',')
    res="<v2:values>"
    for (parameter in param_array)
    {
```

after that, I am not sure how do I iterate over the array and put values for other XML tags. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `StreamingMarkupBuilder` to generate the XML into a String

It won't be pretty-printed, but it will be valid XML as requested:

```
import groovy.xml.*

def input = 'cat,mouse,dog'

String xml = new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
    'v2:values' {
        input.split(',').collect { item ->
            'v2:item'(item)
        }
    }
}


println xml
```

If you need it pretty printed, you will need to know where the schema for `v2` is, as `XmlUtil.serialize` needs the xml to validate

### Edit

If you need it pretty printed, you can switch to `MarkupBuilder`

```
import groovy.xml.*

def input = 'cat,mouse,dog'

def writer = new StringWriter()
new MarkupBuilder(writer).'v2:values' {
    input.split(',').collect { item ->
        'v2:item'(item)
    }
}


println writer.toString()
```